# How to find an x-digit number in a text?

Tags: python, search, text-processing

Is there a better (more efficient) way to find x-digit number (number consisted of x digits) in a text?

My way:

EDIT:

```
for n in range(0,len(text)):
    if  isinstance(text[n:n+x], (int)) and isinstance(text[n:n+x+1] is False:
        result = text[n:n+x]

return result
```

EDIT 2:

```
for n in range(0,len(text)):
    try:  
       int(text[n:n+x])
       result = text[n:n+x]
    except:
       pass

return result
```

Comment: Yes regexps! But how does your text and digits look like?

Comment: @greole I've edited my example. I have many lines, on each line is 5-digit number which I want to get. So I'm wondering how to do that.

Comment: .. I don't think `isinstance` does what you think it does.  `isinstance(somestring[some slice here], int)` will always be False.  A string slice is still a string, even if it's made up of decimal digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re                                             
string = "hello 123 world 5678 897 word"              
number_length = 3                                     
pattern= r"\D(\d{%d})\D" % number_length   # \D to avoid matching 567           
print re.findall(pattern, string)
```

**output**

```
["123","897"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex to achieve that. For example

```
>>> import re

>>> s = "abc 123 45678"
>>> re.search("(\d{5})\D",s).group()
'45678'
```

finds a 5 digit number in s. Or if you have multiple numbers use findall

```
>>> s = "abc 123 45678\nbla foo 65432"
>>> re.findall("(\d{5})\D",s)
['45678', '65432']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exampleText = "abcd12345xyz"

import re

match = re.search('\d+',exampleText)
print(match.group())
```